How do I import data from Google Sheets to a Pandas Dataframe
I am trying to write a script to import data from Google Sheets into my python script as a dataframe to then analyse.
I have watched several videos but I can't seem to make it work more than once (I have several datasets I need to import).
The first dataset I imported seems to have worked using the following code:
import gspread

import pandas as pd

from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file("*api file name*", scopes=scopes)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheets_id = "*google sheet id*"

sheet = client.open_by_key(sheets_id)

faculty_df = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
faculty_df

When I try to run something similar to read in a second dataset from a different google sheet doc (obviously adapting it and changing variable names), it is still bringing through the first dataset.
I assume it is something around the worksheet.get_all_records() code when creating the dataframe, but I am unsure on how to adapt the code to make it work more than once.
Can anyone advise me on how to fix this? or is there a better way overall the get the data in?
Any help or advice at all would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Can you share the code that isn't working?

new_sheets_id = "new_sheet_id"
sheet = client.open_by_key(sheets_id)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
new_df
